# DataTable PrimeNG - Column Toggler

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a datatable with 11 columns. I'm using the toggleable columns feature. I would like to show the 11 column selection options, but initially leave only 4 selected. I studied several options of the MultiSelect component, but I did not find an answer to my question..

Comment: Can you show your code please ?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Simply you need to initialize `selectedColumns` property with some column objects from columns array based on filter of your choice.

this an example base on index so only the first two columns will be selected as default

```
this.selectedColumns = this.columns.filter((c,index) => index < 2);
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-table-toggle)

another way add a default property to columns array and filter the base on it

```
  this.columns = [
      { field: 'vin', header: 'Vin' , default:true },
      { field: 'year', header: 'Year' },
      { field: 'brand', header: 'Brand' },
      { field: 'color', header: 'Color' ,default:true }
    ];

  this.selectedColumns = this.columns.filter((c) => c.default);
```